# Create a GeoDataFrame from a GeoJSON object

Tags: python, gis, geojson, geopandas

I have a Feature Collection of polygons and I have to first write it in a temporary file to then load it with `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(tmp_json_file)`, is there any way to not write the temporary file and to  just create the `GeoDataFrame` from the `GeoJSON` object ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `GeoDataFrame.from_features()` function for this. A small example (supposing you have a geojson FeatureCollection):

```
In [1]: from geojson import Feature, Point, FeatureCollection

In [2]: my_feature = Feature(geometry=Point((1.6432, -19.123)), properties={"country": "Spain"})

In [3]: my_other_feature = Feature(geometry=Point((-80.234, -22.532)), properties={'country': 'Brazil'})

In [4]: collection = FeatureCollection([my_feature, my_other_feature])

In [6]: import geopandas

In [7]: geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features(collection['features'])
Out[7]:
  country                 geometry
0   Spain   POINT (1.6432 -19.123)
1  Brazil  POINT (-80.234 -22.532)
```

Comment: It works like a charm for simple polygons, but I have another `FeatureColletion` composed of `Polygons` and `MultiPolygons` and I don't know how to handle the geometry of it

Comment: What do you mean with "how to handle the geometry of it"? Does it fail to create a geopandas GeoDataFrame? (as those can hold a geometry column with different geometry types, so that shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Can you open a separate question for this? (as it is something else, about how to create a FeatureCollection)