# Load GeoJSON into GeoPandas Dataframe - desformated or gives `raise a TypeError`

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I'm trying to load a simple geojson feature to geopandas but, I want to keep all info (properties and other popupinfo) within the geometry. The result, either with GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame it's not satisfatory.

The code:

```py
geojson = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]},"properties": {"name": "Dinagat Islands"}}

test = geopandas.GeoSeries(geojson)
print(test)

test2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geojson)
print(test2)
```

The result:

```
#.GeoSeries
FutureWarning:     You are passing non-geometry data to the GeoSeries constructor. Currently,
    it falls back to returning a pandas Series. But in the future, we will start
    to raise a TypeError instead.
 
 test = geopandas.GeoSeries(geojson)
type                                                  Feature
geometry      {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [125.6, 10.1]}
properties                        {'name': 'Dinagat Islands'}
dtype: object


#.GeoDataFrame
                type       geometry       properties
type         Feature          Point              NaN
coordinates  Feature  [125.6, 10.1]              NaN
name         Feature            NaN  Dinagat Islands
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I just add the geojson object to a list. But I found the library `geojson_utils` which does almost the same things as the `geopandas`. So, if you only work with geojson, use geopandas or fiona to load/convert shp to geojson and then,maybe will be more efficient using geojson_utils.

```py
test2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame([geojson])

# print(test2)

      type                                         geometry                   properties
0  Feature  {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [125.6, 10.1]}  {'name': 'Dinagat Islands'}
```

Other solution is using geojson python lib and `GeoDataFrame.from_features`. See this [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728540/create-a-geodataframe-from-a-geojson-object)